# SSJS HTTP Get method error - Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, http

I am trying to retrieve a template-based email asset using the Content Builder API via a Cloud page. I am having trouble retrieving the template. I am not sure if it is an issue with the structure of the payload or a potential issue with the HTTP Get method. I am getting the following error message:

`Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.Failed to retrieve email template.`

This is the code I have been using to make the request:

```
      Platform.Load("core", "1");

      var clientId = "{{REMOVED}}";
      var clientSecret = "{{REMOVED}}";
      var grantType = "{{REMOVED}}";
      var accountId = "{{REMOVED}}";

      try
      {
        var success = false;
        var accessToken = GetAccessTokenForAPI(clientId, clientSecret, grantType, accountId);
        if (accessToken != null)
        {
          success = retrieveEmailTemplate(accessToken);
        }
        if (success) {
          Write("Retrieved email template.");
        } else {
          Write("Failed to retrieve email template.");
        }
      }
      catch (exc)
      {
       Write("Exception Error: " + Stringify(exc));
    }

      function GetAccessTokenForAPI(clientId, clientSecret, grantType, accountId)
      {
       var url = 'https://{{REMOVED}}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
          var contentType = 'application/json';
          var payload =
          {
            client_id: clientId,
            client_secret: clientSecret,
            grant_type: grantType,
            account_id: accountId
          };

          var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
          if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
             var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
             return tokenResponse.access_token;
          }
          else
          {
            return null;
            Write("Error");
          }
      }

      function retrieveEmailTemplate(accessToken)
      {

          var url = 'https://{{REMOVED}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/query';

          var contentType = 'application/json';

         var headername = ["Authorization"];

         var headervalue = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

         var payload ='{"query":{"leftOperand":{"property":"name","simpleOperator":"equal","value":"{{REMOVED}}"},"logicalOperator":"AND","rightOperand":{"property":"assetType.name","simpleOperator":"equal","value":"templatebasedemail"}},"fields":["name","views","thumbnail","category","content","data"]}';
         try {
            var emailRequest = HTTP.Get(url, contentType, payload, headername, headervalue);
            var emailResult = Platform.Response.Write("Email request: " + emailRequest);
            return emailResult;
            }
        catch(err) {
            Platform.Response.Write("This is an error: " + err);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [simple query version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetSimpleQuery.htm) is a GET, but you need to use POST for the [Advanced Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetAdvancedQuery.htm) version.

[image]

Using [HTTP.POST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpPost.htm) instead will likely get you the expected results.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have swapped out it for a Post request now. I am getting the response now. I have also needed to add `.Response` to the variable `emailResult`. So it now looks like the following: 
` var emailResult = Platform.Response.Write("Email request: " + emailRequest.Repsonse);`. Thanks.